# Pandas DataFrame Row Matching

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames and trying to find the solution for two of the below problems.

1. I want to match "Serial_Number" from df_old to df_new and want to see if they exist in df_old or not. For example if df_old has Serial_Number as 1,2,3 and df_new has Serial Number as 1,3,4 then result should be 1 and 3.
2. Good way to show the data.

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   df_old = pd.DataFrame({'S_No' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'Serial_Number' : [1234,2345,3456,1456,9867], 'Beg_Balance' : [10,20,45,21,29], 'End_Balance' : [2,6,8,5,3]})

   df_new = pd.DataFrame({'S_No' : [1,2,3,4], 'Serial_Number' : [8754,5657,1234,9867], 'Beg_Balance' : [32,20,10,29], 'End_Balance' : [5,6,2,1]})


   df_old_1 =  df_old.sort('Serial_Number',ascending=True)

   df_new_1 =  df_new.sort('Serial_Number',ascending=True)

   print df_old_1

   print df_new_1

   an = df_old_1['Serial_Number'] != df_new_1['Serial_Number']

   bn = df_new_1['Serial_Number'] != df_old_1['Serial_Number']
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're looking for some kind of merge:

```
In [11]: pd.merge(df_old_1, df_new_1, on='Serial_Number')
Out[11]:
   Beg_Balance_x  End_Balance_x  S_No_x  Serial_Number  Beg_Balance_y  End_Balance_y  S_No_y
0             10              2       1           1234             10              2       3
1             29              3       5           9867             29              1       4
```

*see more in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).*

Comment: @andy... unfortunately I just want a final data frame which says that Serial Number in New are not found in old. Something like "NOT IN" operator in SQL and SAS language.

Comment: Hmmm appears i misread this question... I think ~df.serial.isin(df2.serial) may be what youre after... Also there a question about "series algebra" somewhere, will try and dig up later